# Azure File Share Mapped Drive is not visible to all the local user accounts, We are not using Azure AD

Tags: windows, azure, azure-storage

All,

We are using Azure File Share, and we are mapping this file share on the Azure VM (Windows).

On this VM we have multiple local user accounts, this VM is not part of the AD.

Now, this mapped drive is not visible to other local user accounts, is there any way we can map the drive so that all the local users can see it. any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: When we mount azure file share, we will store username password in Credential Manager.  In normal, every user has one Credential Manager and other users cannot access it. So other users cannot access the file share.

Comment: Regarding the issue, I think we need to create the Credential for every user.

Comment: Thank you @JimXu I found a Small Workaround,

Answer (score 0):

Step1:Download the SysinternalsSuite and unzip it

https://download.sysinternals.com/files/SysinternalsSuite.zip

Step2: Open the Command Prompt with administrative mode and navigate to the SysinternalsSuite folder.

Step3: Run the below command.

psexec -i -s cmd.exe

Step4:It will open another command prompt window with a system account. Run the below command to map the drive.

net use T: \mystorage.file.core.windows.net\drive /pass:6ymdZxhlfjhgjslahdgdkhsgdjru123455MoVVdqiSutRh38O1g== /user:"Azure\mystorage"

Step5: Log off the user and login back in. The Drive will be a map for all the local user accounts.

Please Note: When you restart the server, the drive will disappear.